# Why is the WordPress user meta key not being created / meta value being accessed?

Tags: wordpress

I am try to create a user meta key (with value) but only if the current user does not already have the meta key.

Then I want to get the user meta value.

Here is my code. I'm sure I'm doing something very stupid but when I run the code, either the logged in user's meta is not created or it is not fetched, as the result of $userCredit is always blank.

What have I done wrong?

```
$user_id = wp_get_current_user();
$meta_key = "ai_anna_credit";
$meta_value = 150;

$userCredit = get_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key);

if ( $userCredit == "") {

   update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
   $userCredit = get_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[wp_get_current_user()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/) Retrieves the current user object. So you need to access "ID" from the object.

```
$user_id    = wp_get_current_user()->ID;
```

Another, `$userCredit = get_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key );` returns array by default. If you want to get a single value then you need to add a third parameter `$userCredit = get_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, true );` as per the [get_user_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/#user-contributed-notes).

Now try if it works for you or not.

```
$user_id    = wp_get_current_user()->ID;
$meta_key   = 'ai_anna_credit';
$meta_value = 150;

$userCredit = get_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, true );

if ( $userCredit == '' ) {

    update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
    $userCredit = get_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key );

}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much for your explanation and example code! Much appreciated.